# Density of ionised air

Tags: electrostatics, aerodynamics

Is ionised air less dense than ordinary air, if so, by how much?

Comment: How would ionizing the air increase the pressure?

Comment: I thought that it would lead to an abundance of either negative or positive ions leading to repulsion. ( And then I imagined that the electrical potential energy would transform into elastic potential energy as the volume increases? )

Comment: This is engineering? It's really a physics question at heart: is ionized air less dense than non-ionized air (and if so, by how much)? If you want it reopened, edit it to rephrase the question that way

Comment: since, for example, a proton and an electron is 13.6 eV heavier than a hydrogen atom: I'm going to say yes.